# Update state based on google places API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, this, state

I'm having trouble understanding how to set state from a callback function.

Google by default gives us this code to [get data from their place API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details)

What I want to know is:

- How can I update state here of "isOpen" based on the received data from that API?

  - I can't do "this.setState" as 'this' doesn't refer to the global state
  - I'm going to then use state "isOpen" (true/false) to declare a variable with conditional JSX.

    ```
    export default class IndexPage extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isOpen: false,
        };
     }


    componentDidMount() {
     let map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

    });
    const request = { placeId: "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4" };
    const getPlaceById = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map).getDetails(
    request,
    callback
    );

    function callback(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log(place.opening_hours.open_now); //returns true or false

        //set isOpen to state

        }
     }
    }
    }
    ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring callback without binding it to component returns 'setState of undefined' error.

declare callback function as a class method of your react component.

```
class X extends React.Component {
    ...

    callback(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {               
            // set state here
            this.setState({ isOpen: place.opening_hours.open_now})
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

then inside your componentDidMount() call, bind your callback method as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {});    
    const request = { placeId: "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4" };
    const getPlaceById = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map).getDetails(
        request,
        // you need to bind `this` to callback function to use callback in HTML DOM
        (place, status) => this.callback(place, status)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, bind this to your callback inside the constructor

```
this.callback = this.callback.bind(this);
```

You will have to edit the following

```
const getPlaceById = new 
google.maps.places.PlacesService(map).getDetails(
request,
this.callback
);
```

For more info, read https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html